# Why does this Error converting data type varchar to bigint happen?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Why am I facing this error ? It is very annoying and tried solving it but doesn't work.

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint

It throws error about this value **2000100020502**.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Reports_UnDisbursedSalaryReport]
(
    @FromDate SMALLDATETIME,
    @ToDate SMALLDATETIME,
    @OfficeID INT = 3,
    @Type INT = 1,
    @EmployerUniqueID VARCHAR(15) = '',
    @EmployeeUniqueID VARCHAR(15) = ''
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @EmployerUniqueID = 
        CASE 
           WHEN LEN(@EmployerUniqueID) <=0 
              THEN NULL 
              ELSE @EmployerUniqueID 
        END
    SET @EmployeeUniqueID = 
        CASE 
           WHEN LEN(@EmployeeUniqueID) <= 0
              THEN NULL 
              ELSE @EmployeeUniqueID 
        END

    DECLARE @Branches TABLE (BranchID INT)

    IF @Type = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Branches 
            SELECT BranchID 
            FROM vw_OrganizationTree 
            WHERE OrganizationID = @OfficeID
    END

    IF @Type = 2
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Branches 
            SELECT BranchID 
            FROM vw_OrganizationTree 
            WHERE CompanyID = @OfficeID
    END

    IF @Type = 3
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Branches 
            SELECT BranchID 
            FROM vw_OrganizationTree 
            WHERE BranchID = @OfficeID
    END

    SELECT 
        DATEADD(HOUR, 4, PF.EntryDateTime) 'EntryDateTime', 
        C.CompanyName, B.BranchName, 
        @FromDate as 'Fromdate', @ToDate as 'Todate', 
        E.EmployerName, RE.EmployeeName, RE.EmployeeUniqueID, 
        FE.IncomeFixedComponent, FE.IncomeVariableComponent,
        S.StatusDescription
    FROM
        File_EdrEntries FE 
    JOIN 
        RegisteredEmployees RE ON RE.EmployeeUniqueID = FE.EmployeeUniqueID
    JOIN 
        Employers E ON E.ID = RE.Employer_ID 
    JOIN 
        Branches B ON B.BranchID = E.Branch_ID 
    JOIN 
        companies C ON C.COMPANYID = B.COMPANY_ID
    JOIN 
        Statuses S ON S.StatusID = FE.Status_ID 
    JOIN 
        PAFFiles PF ON PF.ID = FE.PAFFile_ID
    WHERE 
        PF.EntryDateTime >= @FromDate 
        AND PF.EntryDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate) 
        AND Status_ID IN (1, 2) 
        AND E.Branch_id IN (SELECT BranchID From @Branches)
        AND CAST(E.EmployerID AS BIGINT) = ISNULL(CAST(@EmployerUniqueID AS BIGINT), CAST(E.EmployerID AS BIGINT))
        AND CAST(RE.EmployeeUniqueID AS BIGINT) = ISNULL(CAST(@EmployeeUniqueID AS BIGINT), CAST(RE.EmployeeUniqueID AS BIGINT))
END
```

Comment: what line is giving the error? which variable or field contains 2000100020502? There are several cast statements, do you know which one is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure all the values in the column `EmployerID` and `EmployeeUniqueID` are proper numeric values?

Comment: anywhere when BIGINT is present

Comment: what can be the workaround ?

Comment: Are you sure that the value you've presented as being the problem is exactly the text you've seen/shown us? I.e. could there be any hidden/unprintable whitespace characters that are also part of the value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use try_convert function. I assume that you are using sql server 2012 and above.....

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 4, PF.EntryDateTime) 'EntryDateTime'
    ,C.CompanyName
    ,B.BranchName
    ,@FromDate AS 'Fromdate'
    ,@ToDate AS 'Todate'
    ,E.EmployerName
    ,RE.EmployeeName
    ,RE.EmployeeUniqueID
    ,FE.IncomeFixedComponent
    ,FE.IncomeVariableComponent
    ,S.StatusDescription
FROM File_EdrEntries FE
JOIN RegisteredEmployees RE ON RE.EmployeeUniqueID = FE.EmployeeUniqueID
JOIN Employers E ON E.ID = RE.Employer_ID
JOIN Branches B ON B.BranchID = E.Branch_ID
JOIN companies C ON C.COMPANYID = B.COMPANY_ID
JOIN Statuses S ON S.StatusID = FE.Status_ID
JOIN PAFFiles PF ON PF.ID = FE.PAFFile_ID
WHERE PF.EntryDateTime >= @FromDate
    AND PF.EntryDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate)
    AND Status_ID IN (
        1
        ,2
        )
    AND E.Branch_id IN (
        SELECT BranchID
        FROM @Branches
        )
    AND try_convert(BIGINT, E.EmployerID) = ISNULL(try_convert(BIGINT, @EmployerUniqueID), try_convert(BIGINT, E.EmployerID))
    AND try_convert(BIGINT, RE.EmployeeUniqueID) = ISNULL(try_convert(BIGINT, @EmployeeUniqueID), try_convert(BIGINT, RE.EmployeeUniqueID))
```

If the try_convert function works in your case then you data contains alphanumeric characters.

Comment: HAHAHA wow man, it worked, but still i don't get, how it worked ? i don't see the difference

Comment: It seems one of the employerid or employeeuniqueid would contain non numeric character. Please identify that record. I dont know why are you converting varchar to bigint.

Comment: ok but now i am using your code for work, is it ok to proceed with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is when casting a column not the variable: 
`CAST(E.EmployerID  AS BIGINT)`or `CAST(RE.EmployeeUniqueID AS BIGINT)`.
Are you sure that all `Employers.EmployerID` or `RegisteredEmployees.EmployeeUniqueID` can be casted as `bigint`?

Comment: umm. What can be the work around ? casting is not necessary but when i remove cast then it doesn't show anything

Comment: @Cuckoo If columns are varchar you should compare them to a varchar.

Answer (score 0):

`select convert( bigint , 2000100020502)`

[It is fine here in SQL Server 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6D20.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cast(column_name as nvarchar).